# How to make desktop icon for keyboard shortcut (linux)

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, kde

I use Linux Mint 18.3 with KDE Plasma 5.8. There's a shortcut for all open windows view (ctrl+F8 I believe). It looks similar to Activities view from Gnome. I would like to have an icon for desktop or panel which will execute that keyboard shortcut.

Any ideas how to do that? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Does KDE have a "keyboard shortcuts" setting, where you can look what the shortcut actually runs, then copy that into a .desktop or .sh file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

And then create file (for example Present Windows.desktop) with contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=xdotool key Control+F8
GenericName=
Icon=exec
MimeType=
Name=Present Windows
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
```

Enjoy pressing!